# Vertical JScrollPane cuts off its children's right side

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

At first, we have a `JPanel`. Its width can be varied because of its environment and context. It contains some components (e.g. `JLabels`, for simplicity) in vertical order. Some of this components' content width is too large to show:

[image: Overflow with a JPanel]

This works very well until we have a lot of items. So, we put the panel into a `JScrollPane` with the `HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER` flag. This is my expected result:

[image: Expected result with JScrollPane]

But actually something else happens. Size of the second label with the long text is not forced, and the panel grows out of the viewport:

[image: Actually happens]

What is the simplest correct solution?

### Comments

- Actually this can be more complex with a wide variety of components, so using a `JList` is not a suitable solution.
- I use default components with default settings. I would like to find a solution with the least amount of explicit setup.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to implement the `Scrollable` interface for your panel to force the width of the panel to fit in the viewport of the scroll pane.

An easy way to do this is to use the [Scrollable Panel](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/12/20/scrollable-panel/).

For example you might use:

```
ScrollablePanel panel = new ScrollablePanel(...);
panel.setScrollableWidth( ScrollablePanel.ScrollableSizeHint.FIT );
```

Edit:

If you implement the `Scrollable` interface yourself the simplest implementation might be something like:

```
@Override
public Dimension getPreferredScrollableViewportSize()
{
    return getPreferredSize();
}

@Override
public int getScrollableUnitIncrement(Rectangle visible, int orientation, int direction)
{
    return 1;
}

@Override
public int getScrollableBlockIncrement(Rectangle visible, int orientation, int direction)
{
    return 20;
}

@Override
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportWidth()
{
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean getScrollableTracksViewportHeight()
{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Absolutely correct. But I still hope it can be solved with the native components' functionality.

Comment: @DávidHorváth It is native components functionality.  The `Scrollable` interface was designed so components can work with a JScrollPane. Some components, like JTable, JTextArea implement the `Scrollable` interface. JList also implements it but you already stated it was not a valid solution. However, JPanel doesn't implement it which is why you need to implement it yourself. You don't have to use the suggested class. You can implement the  5 `Scrollable` methods yourself if you want.

Comment: Scrollable works relatively well. But long labels' behavior is a little strange: no hellip added and text flows into the padding area of the panel and cropped in the right side. This happens even with an exact copy of your methods. What is the solution?

Comment: @DávidHorváth, post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problems. Pictures don't help us understand the layouts you are using. `This happens even with an exact copy of your methods.` - I didn't test those methods. I use the ScrollablePanel so I don't have to duplicate code all the time.

Comment: @camickr14 Oh, no! In my latest comment I just noticed a how-does-anything-like-that-happen problem, hoping that there is a quick tip for it. Just relax, I will accept your answer.

Comment: @DávidHorváth, `Just relax,` - not sure what that comment is about. Every question you ask should have a SSCCE posted with the question. We can't tell what your code is doing based on a picture. The point of a SSCCE is to simplify the problem. Most times when you create a SSCCE you will find the problem yourself and if not, then we have actual code to look at. It is far easier for use to look at code and spot a potential problem then it is to guess what your might be doing.